# Show elements one by one with JS or jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a few DIV's and want to show them one by one.

First, all of them should be `display:none;` in CSS and then I need some **jQuery** script, which I can't figure out how to write.

Only one element should be visible at a time, and the delay should be around 2 secs. The sequence would be:

1. No elements for 2 secs
2. First element visible for 2 secs.
3. No elements visible for 2 secs
4. Second element visible visible for 2 secs
5. and so on... + Loop

Thanks!

Here is a link of what I've done so far. It's not an elegant way to do that, I know. Also, it does not loop- stops after last element is on.
http://jsbin.com/uwubah/7/

HTML:

```
  <div class="dezute">dezute</div>
  <div class="kubikas">kubikas</div>
  <div class="zirkles">zirkles</div>
  <div class="telefonas">telefonas</div>
  <div class="izoliacija">izoliacija</div>
  <div class="dainuoja">dainuoja</div>
```

CSS:

```
.dezute, .kubikas, .zirkles, .telefonas, .izoliacija, .dainuoja{
  display: none;
}
```

jQ:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    setTimeout(function() { 
        $('.dezute').fadeIn(); 
 }, 2000); 
});

$(document).ready(function() { 
    setTimeout(function() { 
        $('.dezute').fadeOut();
        $('.kubikas').fadeIn();
 }, 4000); 
});

$(document).ready(function() { 
    setTimeout(function() { 
        $('.dezute').fadeOut();
        $('.kubikas').fadeOut();
        $('.zirkles').fadeIn();
 }, 6000); 
});

$(document).ready(function() { 
    setTimeout(function() { 
        $('.dezute').fadeOut();
        $('.kubikas').fadeOut();
        $('.zirkles').fadeOut();
        $('.telefonas').fadeIn();
 }, 8000); 
});

$(document).ready(function() { 
    setTimeout(function() { 
        $('.dezute').fadeOut();
        $('.kubikas').fadeOut();
        $('.zirkles').fadeOut();
        $('.telefonas').fadeOut();
        $('.izoliacija').fadeIn();
 }, 10000); 
});

$(document).ready(function() { 
    setTimeout(function() { 
        $('.dezute').fadeOut();
        $('.kubikas').fadeOut();
        $('.zirkles').fadeOut();
        $('.telefonas').fadeOut();
        $('.izoliacija').fadeOut();
        $('.dainuoja').fadeIn();
 }, 12000); 
});
```

Comment: You're going to need to post some code and show what you've tried...

Comment: This is not how SO works. First, you need to help yourself by writing code, then you can come here asking for help if the code you've written is wrong. But you first need to show some effort...

Comment: @Roland Your code is hardly maintainable and only one DOMready is needed, JS is more fun than that: **http://jsbin.com/ifeduj/2/edit**